# Primefaces dataTable with rowspan

Tags: html, jsf, primefaces

I'm quite new with JSF primefaces 3.1. 
I try to build a "complex" table and I cannot find a good solution using dataTable (I need a sorting component).

I would like to build a table equivalent to the following HTML representation, using a basic POJO like that:

```
String field1
String field2
List<String> fields3 // 3 items
String field4

<table border="1">
<tr>
    <td rowspan="3">col1</td>
    <td rowspan="3">col2</td>
    <td>col3.1</td>
    <td rowspan="3">col4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>col3.2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>col3.3</td>
</tr>       
</table>
```

I give maybe too little information, so if you need it, please tell me :)
I hope that my question is clear.

Thank you

Comment: Is the rowspan really necessary? Can't you just render `fields3` in a nested table/list?

Comment: Yes, it could be a nested table/list. I tried subtable, but I can't use it in the cell :s

Comment: Just use `<ui:repeat>` on `fields3` property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A rock-solid and all flexible solution for custom grids is to use <c:forEach> together with Primefaces <p:panelGrid>:

```
<html ... xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
          xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <p:panelGrid>
        <p:row>
            <p:column styleClass="ui-state-default" colspan="2"><!-- header -->
                <h:outputText value="Some Header"/>
            </p:column>
            ...
        </p:row>
        <p:row><!-- other header row -->
            ...
        </p:row>
        <c:forEach items="#{list}" var="element">
            <p:row>
                <p:column styleClass="ui-state-default" rowspan="#{list.sublist.someSizeExpression}"><!-- left rowspan -->
                    <h:outputText value="#{element.name}"/>
                </p:column>
                <c:forEach items="#{element.sublist}" var="subelement">
                    <p:column>
                        <h:selectBooleanCheckbox/>
                    </p:column>
                </c:forEach>
            </p:row>
        </c:forEach>
    </p:panelGrid>
</html>
```

It looks nice, Command-Buttons and AJAX works in both Head and Cells.

Answer (score 1):

since you mentioned `primefaces` in your tags.
I recommend you to use [p:panelGrid](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/panelGrid.jsf)

```html
<p:panelGrid>  

    <p:row>  
        <p:column rowspan="3"/>  
        <p:column rowspan="3"/>  
        <p:column rowspan="1"/>  
        <p:column rowspan="3"/>  
    </p:row>  

    <p:row>  
        <p:column/>
    </p:row>  

    <p:row>  
        <p:column/>  
    </p:row>  

</p:panelGrid>
```

Comment: Yes, but I need to sort some columns, so dataTable seems a good choice.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem : primefaces (or richfaces) offers rowspan only for header and footer.

Then I tried to use the icefaces `ace:datatable` component and it run by adding only one attribute in the colum(s) you want to be "rowspanable" : `ace:column` : `groupBy="#{bean.field}"`.

You give as usual a list of rows and this component generates all rowspan automatically (I think by autodetecting neigbourhood of equals values) in the generated html table.

It runs altogether with primefaces components : at this moment I have primefaces outputlabel in the icefaces datatable cells ant this icefaces datatable is inside a primefaces panel.

Comment: I finally implemented my own table :s

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisHouzard For those like me who which to have this functionnality, can you post your solution as an anwser please ?

Comment: RichFaces does support rowspan! We use it in a few places with subtables. Just make sure you use rendered="#{rowKey eq 0}" rowspan="#{bean.listSize}". You can even have e.g. the first column with a rowspan of 10 and the second column with rowspans of 4 and 6 (just and example). You will need another index for the second column though for your rendered.

Answer (score 0):

I would have a look at the RichFaces dataTable. I found it to be more flexible than the PrimeFaces table for complex layouts.

You can use

```
 <rich:collapsibleSubTable
     value="#{bean.getData()}"
     var="line"
     id="subTable"
     rowKeyVar="rowKey"
     width="100%">
<rich:column width="40" rendered="#{rowKey eq 0}" rowspan="#{line.firstColRowSpan}">
    #{line.country}
    </rich:column>
    <rich:column rendered="#{line.index eq 0}" rowspan="#{line.secondColRowSpan}">
       #{line.state}
    </rich:column>
    <rich:column>
    #{line.city}
    </rich:column>
</rich:subtable>
```

so if your line data looks like this:

```
US CA San Francisco 0 (index) 6 (firstColRowSpan) 3 (secondColRowSpan)
US CA LA 1 6 3
US CA Jose 2 6 3
US TX Huston 0 6 2
US TX Dallas 1 6 2
US AZ Phoenix 0 6 1
UK Surrey Guildford 0 1 1
```

The the table would show

```
US  CA     San Francisco
           LA
           Jose
    TX     Huston
           Dallas
    AZ     Phoenix 
UK  Surrey Guildford
```

It is important that if you have buttons/links etc in one of the rowspan columns that you add a rendered="#{rowKey eq 0}" there as well!