# Primefaces Nested table

Tags: primefaces, datatable

I want to represent my list as follows using a datatable in primefaces:

```
+----------+------------+-----------+
|Country   |   Name     |   Age     |
+----------+------------+-----------+
|          |    xxxxx   | 25        |
|          +------------+-----------+        
|    A     |    yyyyy   |  22       |
|          +------------+-----------+
|          |    zzzz    |...
+----------+------------+
|          |            |..
....
```

I have a List:

```
List<MyObject>
```

MyObject has following attributes:

```
Country
Name
Age
```

Comment: What is your requirement ? What is the problem you are facing ?

Comment: What have you tried? Did you look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14031888/1199132) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13649578/how-to-represent-nested-data-in-primefaces-datatable) answers?

Comment: My requirement is to be able to display data of my list grouped by country.

Comment: Do I need to have a `Map<Country,List<MyObject>>`?? I want to be able to display the list of my objects by country, the list that i have actually is a list of MyObject not sorted by country.

Comment: I used the solution proposed in the link: